# Python if else within a try and except

Tags: python, if-statement, urlopen

I have the following python code that works well:

```
try:
    with urlopen("http://my.domain.com/get.php?id=" + id) as response:
        print("Has content" if response.read(1) else "Empty - no content")
except:
    print("URL Error has occurred")
```

But I am trying to change the if else statement within the try to something like this: so that I can run extra code rather than just print a message

```
try:
    with urlopen("http://my.domain.com/get.php?id=" + id) as response:
        if response.read(1):
            print("Has content")
        else:
            print("Empty - no content")
except:
    print("URL Error has occurred")
```

But the above is not working, giving an error related to indent

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Try to remove the try-except block and run the code behind the try: statement. You will then see what's wrong.

Comment: you missed quotes around "Has content"

Comment: also, define `not working`

Comment: this is why you should only catch the narrowest-possible exception, i.e. `URLError`.

Comment: Also you should write your if else statement not on a single line. It will improve readability

Comment: i'm getting indent related error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put the exception into a variable and print that too

```
except Exception as e:
    print("Error has occurred", e)
```

If you indenting looks like the original question, then that may be your problem - mixing tabs with spaces

Comment: You're correct there was some spaces i think in the tabs so i took everything out and re-indented and its solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should separate different areas that an exception could occur with different `try` blocks.

Specifically, rather than surround `with` with a `try` block, use the `contextlib` module to handle these details. This is straight out of [PEP 343](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/), example 6:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def opened_w_error(filename, mode="r"):
    try:
        f = open(filename, mode)
    except (IOError, err):
        yield None, err
    else:
        try:
            yield f, None
        finally:
            f.close()   

with opened_w_error('/tmp/file.txt', 'a') as (f, err):
    if err:
        print ("IOError:", err)
    else:
        f.write("guido::0:0::/:/bin/sh\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing quotation marks in the first if. Should be

```
if response.read(1):
    print("Has content")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try an else clause to run your code

From http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html

> The try ... except statement has an optional else clause, which, when
>   present, must follow all except clauses. It is useful for code that
>   must be executed if the try clause does not raise an exception. For
>   example:

```
for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
    try:
        f = open(arg, 'r')
    except IOError:
        print 'cannot open', arg
    else:
        print arg, 'has', len(f.readlines()), 'lines'
        f.close()
```